# Large local postgres database-- a doomed errand?

Tags: postgresql

I pulled a month's Reddit comments into a postgres9.5 database on my local win7 machine.

It has 70.6mn rows of 9 text columns.

Once I finished creating it (took about 2.5 hours), even the simplest queries take forever.  Select `count(id) from comments` ran for five minutes before it spit an answer.

I created an index on 'id' but that barely accelerated the `select count(id)` query.

This is a simplistic default install of Postgres.

I was planning on using `ts_vectors` to do text search on this.  But if even a simple count of rows takes so long, it's far fetched to think of more elaborate queries.

My question is, where should I look for settings/configurations to improve this if possible.  Or is this just too big a file (20gb database) for postgres to operate queries 'quickly'?

```
-- auto-generated definition
CREATE TABLE comments
(
  id           TEXT NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT comments_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY,
  body         TEXT,
  author       TEXT,
  subreddit_id TEXT,
  link_id      TEXT,
  parent_id    TEXT,
  score        TEXT,
  subreddit    TEXT
);
COMMENT ON TABLE comments IS 'Reddit Comments';
```

Here's the simplest quest with explain:

```
postgres=# explain (analyze, buffers) select count(id) from comments;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Aggregate  (cost=2368842.45..2368842.46 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=243275.182..243275.183 rows=1 loops=1)
       Buffers: shared hit=996371 read=1273823
       ->  Seq Scan on comments  (cost=0.00..2349112.76 rows=7891876 width=8) (actual time=0.002..236984.770 rows=70609487 loops=1)
             Buffers: shared hit=996371 read=1273823
     Planning time: 0.060 ms
     Execution time: 243275.209 ms
    (6 rows)
```

RE: Remarks in the comments disparaging me for not normalizing the table, and my datatypes.  Since I'm principally interested in text analysis of the `body` column, the other columns are just metadata for me. I am not sure why I want to make the schema more complicated for something I don't need.  And the id of a comment IS a string.  Thus I used text columns as the datatype.

I also looked at the '[tuning settings](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)' recommendations versus my default settings.  The `shared_buffer` setting (128MB now, could be 512MB) is said to not matter much on windows.  I could also increase effective_cache_size from 4GB to 8GB on my 16GB win7 box.  But I didn't see much else.

====EDIT:  I ran `vacuum, analyze comments` and then reran the simple `select count(*) from comments`

```
postgres=# explain (analyze, buffers) select count(id) from comments;
                                                                          QUERY    PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2541076.54..2541076.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=326085.763..326085.763 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=276729 read=721831
   ->  Index Only Scan using comments_pkey on comments  (cost=0.57..2364549.52 rows=70610808 width=8) (actual time=122.348..321066.327 rows=70609487 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 16408753
         Buffers: shared hit=276729 read=721831
 Planning time: 0.402 ms
 Execution time: 326085.788 ms
(7 rows)


postgres=# select relname, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum, last_analyze, last_auto
analyze FROM pg_stat_all_tables where schemaname = 'public';

 relname  |         last_vacuum          |        last_autovacuum        |         last_analyze          |       last_autoanalyze
----------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 posts    |                              | 2017-10-08 10:10:08.060342+08 |                               | 2017-10-08 11:53:20.025502+08
 comments | 2017-10-08 21:55:10.26989+08 | 2017-10-08 12:01:57.429096+08 | 2017-10-08 22:12:27.708228+08 | 2017-10-08 14:46:58.541407+08
(3 rows)
```

***UPDATE***

**QUESTIONS ABOUT DRIVE:**

It seems the D: harddrive is **enormously** slow!  I moved the database to C: and the `select count(*) from comments` query took 10 seconds instead of 5 minutes.  (I've no idea what is wrong with this drive.  the benchmark test is taking forever too) 
[image]
[image: The fast drive]

**SEVERAL QUERY RESULTS:**

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('comments_pkey'))  # 1516 MB
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('comments'))       # 17 GB

# avg=7, stddev=0, max=7, min=7
SELECT avg(octet_length(id)), stddev(octet_length(id)), max(octet_length(id)), min(octet_length(id)) from comments
```

**RE-RUNNING EXPLAIN ON THE ORIGINAL QUERY**

```
postgres=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select count(id) from comments;

QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2010570.45..2010570.46 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=11200.379.
.11200.379 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=20715 read=193157
   ->  Index Only Scan using comments_pkey on comments  (cost=0.57..1834253.61 r
ows=70526736 width=8) (actual time=0.035..7085.082 rows=70609487 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
         Buffers: shared hit=20715 read=193157
 Planning time: 0.062 ms
 Execution time: 11200.404 ms
(7 rows)
```

Comment: ... or should I use the correct data types and normalize to at least 3NF?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the complete query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: The estimated number of rows is 7M, the actual number 70M. Did you run analyze after the import?

Comment: @wildplasser I have posted results after a `vaccum, analyze` order.

Comment: Is it possible your PC has a *really* slow disk? Please show `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('comments_pkey'))` and `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('comments'))`. Also, is the `id` of `comments` generally wide? Please show `select avg(octet_length(id)), stddev(octect_length(id)) from comments`. And finally, does the comment ever contain characters outside the 7-bit US-ASCII range? Do you need it to support national language collation and sort? If not, consider declaring the column `COLLATE "C"`; this will make sorting *immensely* faster.

Comment: "*The shared_buffer setting is said to not matter much on windows*" - whoever told you that is wrong. Values beyond 4GB did not show much improvement in older versions but that has not been true since I think 9.4 or 9.5

Comment: What are you storing in that `id` column? Nearly 1 million index blocks for 70 million rows indicates a pretty wide primary key. Your harddisk indeed looks like it's pretty slow: approx. 5 minutes to read ~5GB is way below what a current harddisk should deliver

Comment: This comment might not be relevant - you'd need to be the judge of that - but if you're primarily interested in text searching you're probably using the wrong tool altogether. Do you know of Elastic Search?

Comment: @CraigRinger  I edited my post, with the results of those queries. Plus the discovery (by running benchmarks, and by moving the database file) that the original drive is ENORMOUSLY slow compared to my other drive.   The comment text has lots of foreign characters (it's from reddit), so I don't think I can rely on just US ASCII charset.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I saw this remark: "Note that on Windows, large values for shared_buffers aren't as effective, and you may find better results keeping it relatively low and using the OS cache more instead. On Windows the useful range is 64MB to 512MB." from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  The 'id' column is just 7-character alphanumeric id code.

Comment: @user3556757 Then I strongly suspect you will benefit from re-defining the `id` column with `COLLATE "C"`. As for the hard drive, run a S.M.A.R.T test on it. It's highly likely that it's failing and trying to reallocate bad sectors or something similar.

Comment: That Wiki page is out of date. The comment on the max. size for Windows has e.g. been removed from [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#runtime-config-resource-memory) See the [discussion on the mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAA4eK1%2BmwaYpM5B85UTM1fqfoD-ujAhh-6oOryAvZzS_qG1iYA%40mail.gmail.com#CAA4eK1+mwaYpM5B85UTM1fqfoD-ujAhh-6oOryAvZzS_qG1iYA@mail.gmail.com)

Comment: Did you run `vacuum full` on that table between the tests? The last execution plan shows that the `comments_pkey` is about 5 times smaller than in the previous execution plans (213872 blocks vs. 998560 blocks)

Comment: @AdamBenson No I wasn't aware of it before now. It looks quite interesting and maybe something I should learn to use, rather than homemade search.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I ran `vacuum, analyze comments` earlier today.

Comment: @CraigRinger i have `ALTER` to include the `COLLATE "C"`.   Btw, I ran a S.M.A.R.T. diagnostic too (crystalDisk) on the drive, and the results claimed it was perfectly health. Quite weird.  Couldn't find any driver updates or firmware updates for the drive either (wd10SPCX)

Comment: @user3556757 In case you didn't find the link you can download it free from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch. It runs under JAVA. Takes a while to get used to it. But it really is very powerful. Docs are at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html We were going to write our own keyword search solution for docs running into the millions, we're not going to bother now - we're just going to throw it all at ES.

Comment: SMART health check tends to lie on consumer drives, because manufacturers don't like returns. I've had SMART pass tests on drives which completely fail to do any actual I/O. I find the extended self-test more useful - it takes a few hours to actually scan the drive for bad sectors. Looking at the vendor diagnostics to see the error rates, bad sector counts, etc can also be informative.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think overlooked the obvious --  the Samsung drive is an SSD.  The Western Digital drive is not...  huge difference in performance there.